# how to convert this percent calculation in PHP?

Tags: php

i have this formula which I translated from a spreadsheet cell formula

```
((0.001559 * 6224 ) + 2.476) / 2 * 101.61%
```

the multiply and divide part is simple...but my problem is with the percent thing,
how to multiply quotient with 101.61% in PHP ?

Comment: where did you get that 1.0161 ?

Comment: @sasori 101.61% = 101.61/100 = 1.0161

Answer (score 1):

just multiply with the percentage divided by 100 - so 101.61% becomes `* 1.0161`:

```
((0.001559 * 6224 ) + 2.476) / 2 * 1.0161
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
((((0.001559 * 6224 ) + 2.476) / 2) / 100 ) * 101.61
```